# Eclipse BPEL "assign" expression can't input

Tags: eclipse, bpel

I use eclipse to write a BPEL helloworld.But when I want to edit assign's expression,the textarea can't input anything.Why?And how to solve?

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug in Eclipse BPEL designer. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378997

You could use older version of Eclipse to work around this problem.

It works fine in Eclipse Indigo.